# how to get cmake to use the gnu stack of tools under msys2 (mingw)

Tags: c++, cmake

On Windows 10, with an installed msys2, which is a variant of mingw, I have an installed cmake with the gcc toolchain and all the standard tools like make.

The version of g++ is 6.2 and make is 4.2.1  Both are in the path.

When I build using cmake:

```
cmake .
```

it tries to build using nmake and cl.  So somehow because I am on windows cmake is trying to use the visual studio toolchain.

```
export CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++
```

does not help.  The error is:

```
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.8.0
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/clang++.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_87e5f\fast"
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/clang++.exe -- broken
CMake Error at D:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/clang++.exe" is not able to compile a
  simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: D:/git/CSP/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_87e5f\fast"



  Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO"
  "cmTC_87e5f\fast"





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/git/CSP/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/git/CSP/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use MSYS2 toolchain, you need to specify the build system generator explicitly, i.e.

```
cmake -G 'MSYS Makefiles' .
```

Additional note, it's a good practice to separate the application . source file and `cmake`'s generated file, e.g.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G 'MSYS Makefiles' ..
```

Comment: Still get an error: # error "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is set to a C++ compiler"
exporting CMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang does not help.  Any suggestions

Comment: Did you install both `gcc` and `g++`?

Comment: Also, MSYS2 came with three terminal, MSYS, 32-bit and 64-bit. In wich terminal did you execute the `cmake` command? It also has three `cmake` version (`mingw-w64-i686-cmake`, `mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` and `msys/cmake`), which one did you install?

Comment: If you need to specify the compiler explicitly, add `-D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc` when executing `cmake`.

Comment: in the path, g++ version 6.2 as well as clang++, everything w64-x86_64

Comment: I have both gcc/g++ and clang/clang++ installed and both are in the path. I don't face any problem when running cmake. Perhaps you can use `cmake-gui` (make sure `qt` is installed) and then specify the compiler (and other parameters) through GUI.

Comment: In addition to what @putu said about the 3 flavours of Msys2 that you need to understand and handle (Msys2 native, which is Cygwin and thus a Unix, and the two Windows cross environments), it might also be of use to know that there are different cmake:s available for Msys, One for the native environment, which does not (currently) know about "MSYS Makefile" generator, and the mingwXX ones, which insists that you are running Windows...)